# C# - Serializing and deserializing methods

Tags: c#, serialization, web

Firstly, sorry if this has been answered elsewhere; I looked around, but the few threads and pages I found on this topic confused me quite a bit as I am fairly new to serialisation.
I am making a C# application in which I want to be able to send a function over the Internet. After a quick Google search, I came across serialization. I attempted to serialize and deserialize my method with the following:

```
public static string ObjectToString(object obj)
{
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        new BinaryFormatter().Serialize(ms, obj);
        return Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
    }
}

public static object StringToObject(string base64String)
{
    byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64String);
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes, 0, bytes.Length))
    {
        ms.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        ms.Position = 0;
        return new BinaryFormatter().Deserialize(ms);
    }
}
```

But it threw an exception when attempting to convert to a string. I added `[Serializable()]` to it, and then the method simply did nothing.

After some more Googling, I found that in C# you can't do this with the default methods. So is it possible to do this at all, and if not, is there any practical way to go about sending a method over a TcpClient?
Sorry if this is a stupid question.

Thanks in advance,

-Matthew

Comment: First rule of distributed computing: Don't distribute your objects http://martinfowler.com/bliki/FirstLaw.html

Answer (score 1):

Methods are not serializable, so no; you cannot do this.

If you are trying to do an RPC call; you can serialize the name and parameters so you can use reflection on the other side, or just use an existing framework like WCF.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Is it possible to do this using, say, DLLs?

Comment: @user52303 Could you clarify? DLLs and networking are not similar concepts

Comment: As in, have methods in DLLs on a server that can be downloaded to make use of their functions. I don't know how referencing DLLs works - are they implemented at compile time, or can they be dynamically referenced?

Comment: @user52303 They *can* be dynamically loaded (`Assembly.Load`) but you are losing a lot in terms of type safety, knowing what methods exist, etc. You would be going off of nothing but reflection at that point. Could it work? Sure. Is it advisable? Not really. Perhaps you could describe the overall problem you are trying to solve.